# Host Django site on windows on lan

Tags: django, uwsgi, fastcgi

I have a site that I want to expose to a bunch of colleagues that serves as an interface for some Machine learning tools.

I’ve made the site in Django 2.0 and would like to serve it from a small windows PC under my desk, and then from a more dedicated server once it’s operational.

I’ve had a look around and it looks like my options are using uWSGI or Django it self to serve the site. Obviously Django is mich slower, but on a PC with an i5 i recon it should be able to handle a couple of requests a minute, which is the peak traffic I’m expecting.

FastCGI appears to be depreciated, so what other options, prioritizing ease of confit on my part are there?

Comment: What's wrong with using uwsgi as you mention? Another alternative is gunicorn, but either of these are perfectly fine.

Comment: Gunicorn and Nginx is what I’m familiar with but they are Linux only. I’ve heard good things about waitress a gunicorn adaptation for windows. I’m after any experience in this problem as I’m a very new to this hosting stuff and want to find a very simple option, and as described, security and performance are secondary concerns.

Comment: I use [wfastcgi 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi) and IIS without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So anyone in a similar situation:

I ended up using `waitress` as the server and `whitenoise` to serve the static files.

This appears to work sufficiently fast and requires little configuration, once you have have worked out how to get the static files going with `whitenoise`.

Answer (score 0):

Django itself can serve pages to other machines on your network. SImply start the local server with this command

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then, you can access the local website by requesting `http://<dev_machine_ip>:8000`. Obviously, this is a very simple and inefficient solution if you want to provide this website to many users connected all at the same time. But for tests/demo purpose, it is very handy